# What are the common acronyms in Materials Modelling?

Tags: terminology, one-topic-per-answer

Many abbreviations are used in Materials Modelling. For example, we have DFT (density functional theory/discrete Fourier transform), TST (transition state theory) and MD (molecular dynamics).

Which abbreviations are commonly used in Materials Modelling?

---

<sub>This question was taken from the similar [What are common and not so common abbreviations in Operations Research?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/865/what-are-common-and-not-so-common-abbreviations-in-operations-research) on OR.SE.</sub>

Comment: I am not a fan of these rather open ended questions, especially while a site is still trying to figure out its scope.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thanks for your opinion, I thought it would be ok as it was in OR. But I'll see what others think.

Comment: Oh, don't worry, it is my very own opinion. I also believe others in this community will think differently. And obviously, I don't think that these questions should not be asked and answered, but during the finding phase they might become problematic, if there are too many. But let's see what the others think.

Comment: Actually, I'm very interested now, in "what are all the different types of DFT?"  For example TDDFT (time-dependent DFT), OFDFT (orbital-free DFT), KS-DFT (Kohn-Sham DFT), etc.  Now would this be better as a separate question? Or is someone going to be brave enough to answer here? Maybe in 2 days I will put a bounty on it.

Comment: @NikeDattani That's interesting too, but I'll wait for the eventual outcome of this question before asking another of a similar theme. Judging solely by votes it seems there's a 50/50 split in opinion!

Comment: As a noob to any subject area, I love open-ended *review* type questions, as it's a nice way of getting perspective on the entire field without having to dive down into the weeds.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is extremely open as there are thousands of abbreviations which, depending on the particular field of expertise, could be found useful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I will start with acronyms for coupled-cluster, and someone else might answer with acronyms for **basis sets** or for **functionals** or for **many body perturbation theory** or for **composite approaches** or for different **types of SCF**:

---

## Coupled Cluster acronyms

---

**CCSD, CCSDT, CCSDTQ**, ... (coupled cluster with singles, doubles, triples, quadrtuples, etc.)
**CCSD(T), CCSDT(Q)**, ... (coupled cluster with perturbative triples, quadruples, pentuples, etc.)
**EOM-CCSD, EOM-CCSDT**, ... (equation of motion coupled cluster, w/ singles, doubles, etc.)
**STEOM-CCSD**, ... (similarity transformed equation of motion coupled cluster, w/ singles, etc.)
**LR-CCSD, LR-CCSDT**, ... (linear response coupled cluster, a synonym for EOM-CC)
**CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5**, ... (second, third, fourth, fifth-order coupled-cluster, etc.)
**SCS-CC2, SCS-CC3**, ... (spin-component scaled second, third, fourth, coupled-cluster, etc.)
**SOS-CC2, SOS-CC3**, ... (scaled opposite-spin second, third, fourth, coupled-cluster, etc.)
**BCCD, BCCDT, BCCDTQ**, ... (Brueckner coupled cluster with doubles, triples, etc.)
**Mk-MRCCSD, Mk-MRCCSDT**, ... (state-specific Mukherjee multireference coupled-cluster)
**pCCSD, pCCSDT, pCCSDTQ**, ... (parameterized coupled cluster with singles, doubles, etc.)
**TCCSD,TCCSDT,TCCSDDTQ**, .. (tailored coupled cluster with singles, doubles, triples, etc.)
**CVS-EOM-CC**, .. (core-valence separated equation-of-motion coupled-cluster)

**RCCSD**: partially spin-restricted coupled cluster 
**UCCSD**: spin-unrestricted coupled cluster, or unitary coupled cluster
**RDCSD**: partially spin-restricted distinguishable coupled cluster
**UDCSD**: spin-urestricted distinguishable coupled cluster
**pCCD**: pair coupled cluster with doubles (sometimes called **AP1RoG**)

**CCSD-F12, EOM-CCSD-F12**: coupled cluster, or EOM coupled cluster, with F12 correction.
**RI-CC2**: coupled cluster, with the resolution of the identity approximation for the integrals.

Comment: The question has been reopened! Now the voting split of 66/33 seems to marginally support the acceptance of this question.

Comment: BCCSD is wrong. Brueckner orbitals by design set all single excitation operator amplitudes -- that is, the "S" -- to zero. It should be BCCD, BCCDT, etc.

Comment: @jjgoings I've updated the answer. Sorry for my clumsy mistake.

Answer (score 14):

## Density Functionals

**LDA (LSDA):**

- S: Slater (Dirac) exchange functional for a uniform electron gas.
- VWN: Vosko, Wilk, and Nusair 1980 correlation functional fitting the random phase approximation solution to the uniform electron gas.
- PL: Perdew and Wang 1992 local correlation functional (also known as PW or PW92).
- PZ81: Perdew-Zunger parameterization of the LSDA correlation energy from 1981.

**GGA:**

- B88: Becke's 1988 exchange functional which includes Slater exchange and gradient corrections of the density.
- PBE: Exchange and Correlation functional of Perdew, Burke and Ernzerhof (1996).
- PW86: Perdew-Wang correlation functional from 1986 based on the PZ81 LSDA functional.
- PW91: Perdew-Wang correlation functional from 1991.
- LYP: Lee, Yang, Parr correlation functional which includes both local and non-local terms.
- BLYP: B88 exchange plus LYP correlation.

**meta-GGA:**

- SCAN: Strongly Constrained and Appropriately Normed density functional by Sun, Ruzsinszky and Perdew (2015).
- TPSS: Tao, Perdew, Staroverov, and Scuseria exchange and correlation functional.
- revTPSS: Revised TPSS functional.
- BR: Becke and Rousel exchange functional.

**Hybrid or Hyper-GGA:**

- TPSSh: Hybrid functional using the TPSS functionals.
- B3LYP: Becke three-parameter hybrid functional with VWN local correlation and LYP non-local correlation, Hartree-Fock exchange, B88 exchange and VWN exchange.
- B3P86: Same as B3LYP except that non-local correlation is provided by P86.
- B3PW91: Same as B3LYP except that non-local correlation is provided by PW91.
- O3LYP: Cohen and Handy's three parameter hybrid functional.
- PBE0: Adamo's reconstruction of PBE into a hybrid functional (1999).
- B97: Becke's 10-parameter density functional with $19.43\%$ HF exchange.
- M06 class: parametrized hybrid functionals of Truhlar and Zhao (2008).
- HFLYP: $100\%$ HF exchange plus LYP GGA correlation.

**Double Hybrid:**

- B2PLYP: Grimme (2006) double hybrid functional built on the B88 exchange and LYP correlation functionals.
- PBE0-DH: Adamo et al. (2013) double hybrid functional built on the PBE0 functional.

**Long-Range Corrected Hybrids:**

- $\omega$B97XD: Chai and Head-Gordon hybrid functional which includes empirical dispersion.
- CAM-B3LYP: Yanai, Tew and Head-Gordon version of B3LYP using the Coulomb-attenuating method.

(This is a preliminary list for the moment, I'll be updating later.)

Comment: I am not sure if "DFT" itself counts.  I think in quantum chemistry when people talking about "DFT" we are referring to "Density Functional Theory" but I am not sure in the field of material modelling will "DFT" means "Discrete Fourier Transform"?

Answer (score 13):

## Basis Sets

Throughout, I use square brackets to denote additional options that can be included, but are not required.

#### Slater:

- STO-nG: Slater Type Orbitals represented by a function of n contracted Gaussian functions

- STO-nG*: Polarized version of STO-nG

Ones that you can commonly find:

- STO-2G
- STO-3G
- STO-4G
- STO-6G
- STO-3G*

#### Pople:

- X-YZG: Split valence double zeta basis functions, where each core orbital is represented by a contracted function on X primitive Gaussians and each valence orbital is represented by two contracted functions with Y and Z primitive Gaussians. Can be extended up to quadruple zeta (e.g. X-YZWVG)
- X-YZG*[*]: Polarization functions on heavy atoms [and hydrogen]. Also written X-YZG(d) [X-YZG(d,p)]
- X-YZ+[+]G: Diffuse functions on heavy atoms [and hydrogen]

[Ones that you can commonly find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry)):

- 3-21G
- 3-21G*
- 3-21G**
- 3-21+G
- 3-21++G
- 3-21+G*
- 3-21+G**
- 4-21G
- 4-31G
- 6-21G
- 6-31G
- 6-31G*
- 6-31+G*
- 6-31G(3df, 3pd)
- 6-311G
- 6-311G*
- 6-311+G*

#### Correlation-Consistent/Dunning:

- [d/t/q]-[aug]-cc-pVXZ: [doubly/triply/quadruply]-[Augmented with diffuse functions] Correlation Consistent Polarized Valence (Double,Triple, Quadruple,...) Zeta
- cc-p[w]CVXZ: Correlation Consistent Polarized [weighted] Core-Valence (Double,Triple, Quadruple,...) Zeta
- cc-pV(X+d)Z: Additional tight d-functions added for second and later row elements.
- cc-pVXZ-PP: With Pseudopotentials
- cc-pVXZ-DK: Relativistic Douglas-Kroll contraction
- cc-pVXZ-X2C: Relativistic Exact 2-Component contraction
- cc-pVXZ-F12: Reoptimized for better convergence with F12 explicitly correlated methods
- [jul,jun,may,apr]-cc-pVXZ: Calendar basis set variations. Relative to Aug, Jul removes diffuse functions from H and He. Jun, May, and Apr remove the one, two, and three highest angluar momentum diffuse functions, respectively, from all atoms.

#### Karlsruhe

- def2-XVP[P][D]: Reoptimized Turbomole Basis Functions (def2=default 2). (Single, Double, Triple,...) Valence Polarization [Additional set of Polarization] [Set of Diffuse functions]

Ones that you can commonly find:

- def2-SV(P)
- def2-SVP
- def2-SVPD
- def2-TZVP
- def2-TZVPD
- def2-TZVPP
- def2-TZVPPD
- def2-QZVP
- def2-QZVPD
- def2-QZVPP
- def2-QZVPPD

#### Polarization-Consistent/Jensen

- [aug]pc[seg]-n: [Augmented with Diffuse functions] Polarization consistent [segmented contraction]. n denotes how much higher in angular momentum the polarization functions are compared to the isolated atom.

#### Miscellaneous

- ANO: Atomic Natural Orbitals
- ECP: Effective Core Potential
- LanL2DZ: Los Alamos National Lab Double Zeta (double zeta for small atoms, Los Alamos ECP after Na).
- BSSE: Basis Set Superposition Error

#### To Be Continued

Comment: +1. I was waiting for someone to do this! Adding in double-diffuse: d-aug, jul (instead of aug), OPTRI, F12, X2C, etc.  ... Dunning basis sets could even have their own separate category here!

Comment: Don't forget the cc-pV(X+d)Z sets which are a common stumbling block - the original cc-pVXZ sets yield poor results for second-row and heavier atoms due to missing tight d functions.

generally contracted pc-n sets missing. Likewise Jensen's property optimized sets.

d- and t-aug could be also added to cc and pc sets.

Comment: @SusiLehtola absolutely a lot more to add. I tried to get a good spread of some of the most popular basis sets so the answer could at least stand on its own until I had a chance to add more.

Comment: Feel free to revert my last edit if I went overboard, but I'm preparing some lecture notes and plan to provide screenshots of this answer, and I wanted to show the vastness of basis set names. The Wikipedia page has exactly the same lists that I added in my last edit, but the formatting isn't as nice/consistent (although they have explanations next to each basis set name, which can be nice).

Answer (score 10):

## Quantum Monte Carlo

[What are the types of Quantum Monte Carlo?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1594/5)

**Methods**

- SSE QMC: Stochastic Series Expansion QMC
- SAC: Stochastic Analytic Continuation (an add-on technique for real-time dynamics)
- VMC: [Variational Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Monte_Carlo)
- DMC: [Diffusion Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_Monte_Carlo)
- t-VMC: [Time-dependent variational Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-dependent_variational_Monte_Carlo)
- CT-QMC: [Continuous time QMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_quantum_Monte_Carlo)
- DDQMC (or DDMC): [Diagrammatic determinantal QMC]
- PIMC: [Path integral Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_Monte_Carlo)

**Packages**

- ALF: [Algorithms Lattice Fermions](https://gitpages.physik.uni-wuerzburg.de/ALF/ALF_Webpage/) (Auxiliary-field QMC package)
- ALPS: [Algorithms and Libraries for Physics Simulations](http://alps.comp-phys.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- [CASINO](https://vallico.net/casinoqmc/what-is-casino/)

Feel free to comment with more suggestions and I can add them to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Molecular dynamics methods:

- MD ([molecular dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics); typically refers to classical molecular dynamics and often atomistic classical molecular dynamics if there is no further qualifications; atomistic means that the basic particle in the model represents an atom)
- CG (coarse-grain; typically refers to MD simulations with models where a single particle represents multiple atoms)
- AIMD ([ab initio molecular dynamics](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0500193102))
- QM/MM ([molecular mechanics/quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QM/MM))
- PME ([particle mesh Ewald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewald_summation); an approximation used to efficiently calculate infinite range electrostatic interactions over a periodic cell)
- MM-PBSA ([molecular mechanics, Poisson-Boltzmann, surface area](https://doi.org/10.1517/17460441.2015.1032936); a method to approximate solvation free energies)
- MM-GBSA ([molecular mechanics, generalized Born, surface area](https://doi.org/10.1517/17460441.2015.1032936); similar to MM-PBSA, but uses the generalized Born approximation)
- CV (collective variable; some collective function of the underlying particle coordinates, which are usually their Cartesian spatial coordinates)
- PES (potential energy surface)
- MCMC ([Markov chain Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo))
- GCMC (Grand canonical Monte Carlo; used for constant chemical potential ensemble simulations)
- FEP ([free energy perturbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_energy_perturbation))
- TI ([thermodynamic integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_integration))
- TRE ([temperature replica exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_tempering))
- HRE (Hamiltonian replica exchange)
- PMF ([potential of mean force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_of_mean_force))
- US (umbrella sampling; a static distribution-based enhanced sampling scheme)
- WHAM ([Weighted Histogram Analysis Method](http://www.alchemistry.org/wiki/Weighted_Histogram_Analysis_Method))
- REUS (replica exchange umbrella sampling)
- MTD, METAD, MetaD ([metadynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadynamics); a dynamic potential-based enhanced sampling scheme)
- ABF (adaptive biasing force; a dynamic force-based enhanced sampling scheme)
- BAR ([Bennett acceptance ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bennett_acceptance_ratio))
- MBAR ([Multistate Bennett acceptance ratio](http://www.alchemistry.org/wiki/Multistate_Bennett_Acceptance_Ratio))
- MLP (machine learning potential)
- SMD (steered molecular dynamics)
- MSM ([Markov state model](https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.7b12191))

Answer (score 6):

### General

- DFT: Density Functional Theory ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/density-functional-theory))
- TDDFT: Time-dependent density functional theory ([...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-dependent_density_functional_theory))
- LDA: Local Density Approximation ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/local-density-approximation))
- GGA: Generalized Gradient Approximation ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/generalized-gradient-approximation))
- HF: Hartree-Fock ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/hartree-fock-method))
- post HF: Post Hartree-Fock ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/post-hartree-fock-methods))
- RHF: Restricted Hartree-Fock ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/restricted-open-shell-hartree-fock))
- UHF: Unrestricted Hartree-Fock ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/unrestricted-hartree-fock-calculation))
- FMO: Fragment Molecular Orbital ([...](https://staff.aist.go.jp/d.g.fedorov/fmo/main.html))
- MP: Møller-Plesset Perturbation Theory ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/mller-plesset-perturbation-theory))
- $k \cdot p$: $k \cdot p$ perturbation theory ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/kp-perturbation-theory))
- MO: Molecular Orbital ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/molecular-orbital))
- HOMO: Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/highest-occupied-molecular-orbital))
- LUMO: Lowest Unoccupied Molecular Orbital ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/lowest-unoccupied-molecular-orbital))
- VB: Valence Band ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/valence-band))
- CB: Conduction Band ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/conduction-band))
- DOS: Density of State ([...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/density-of-state))
- PDOS: Partial Density of State
- LDOS: Local Density of State